# DVD drive suddenly broke

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, dvd

The BIOS doesn't recognize the drive anymore. I was reinstalling windows and suddenly it broke. The drive is used a couple times. I reset the BIOS (removed battery), and tried different settings. I've tried different s-ata cables on different ports on the motherboard. I opened it and the laser was on. The model is Lite-On iHas124-04 CU. I couldn't find information that was this specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've reseated all cables and checked the BIOS, the drive is likely dead. Sounds ridiculous but remember:

- Optical drives cost very little, so you can replace it cheaply
- Optical drives are not highly engineered any more (because they are cheap)
- It is a HIGHLY mechanical component, and reinstalling windows likely gave it a good workout?

My strong suggestion would be to purchase a USB drive. Any modern BIOS / UEFI will see and it and they tend to have more effort put into the engineering.

If Windows go to the point where you can boot into it, it may give you a hint to problems in the device manager, but I would call this very unlikely indeed!